# Changing up the contents of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

If i have a list of integers such as [1,2,3]

How would I remove the `[` and , to make it just 1 2 3 with spaces

I tried converting it to a string and using the split method but I don't know how to convert back into a integer and print it out. I have this:

```
 z = map(str,x.split(" ,"))
```

but like I said i don't know how to make that a integer again and print it out.
I tried:

```
  t = map(int,z)
```

and that did not work.

```
>>>x = [1,2,3]
1 2 3
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of x and what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: I posted a literal solution, however I somehow doubt that your ACTUAL problem lies with displaying this list as a string. I strongly suspect this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem you're actually trying to solve with that list?

Comment: Your question should be: _"How to get a string representation of a list without the `[` and `]`?"_ Furthermore, **please** do yourself a favour and read e.g. http://learnpythonthehardway.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convert to string with space you need to convert all the entries to `str` with `map(str,l)` and join them with `' '.join` , the for reverse to list first you need to split the string with `str.split()` and then convert to int with `map` :

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> ' '.join(map(str,l))
'1 2 3'
>>> string=' '.join(map(string,l))
>>> map(int,string.split())
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make sense. the `[`, `,`, and `]` are what DEFINE it as a list. Those markings are simply the way that Python shows it is a list. If you want to DISPLAY it as something other than a list, you probably want [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). However that requires that each element in the list be a string, so you're left with either:

```
>>> some_list = [1,2,3]
>>> print(some_list)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(" ".join(map(str, some_list)))
1 2 3
```

or:

```
>>> print(" ".join([str(el) for el in some_list]))
1 2 3
```

Comment: `print(" ".join(some_list))` doesn't work on python 2.7. Are you using python3?

Answer (score -1):

```
' '.join(str(i) for i in my_list)
```